# Access php class method from a href

Tags: php, class, methods

I am trying to add a new functionality to a program that is open source. So there is very little documentation and this section is written in php OOP using smarty. I am going to try to keep this simple.

I am trying to duplicate a href to call a method in a class. The href looks like this:

```
<td style="border-style:none;">
<a id="multiprintToFax" href="{$CONTROLLER}prescription&multiprintfax&id={$printm}" onclick="top.restoreSession()" class="css_button"><span>{xl t='Print'} ({xl t='Fax'})</span></a>
</td>
```

This s apart of the working program. I tried to duplicate the call the function/method by doing this:

```
<td>
  <a id="Re_Issue_rx" href="{$CONTROLLER}prescription&Re_Issue_rx" onclick="top.restoreSession()" class="css_button"><span>{xl t='Re-Issue'} ({xl t='Rx'})</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

I setup a method in the Prescription class file like this

```
function Re_Issue_rx(){
    return 'Issued';
}
```

I get an error message that says:

```
  The action trying to be performed: Re_Issue_rx does not exist controller: Prescription
```

Since this is wrong, what is the proper way to call the method/function from the Prescription class?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question came moments after posting this.

The call to the method should have followed the convention setup by the controller.

```
  Re_Issue_rx
```

I had to change it to match the naming convention. Which is

```
 ReIssueRx_action
```

Once I did this, then it posted the 'Issued' to let me know it accessed the method.

thanks!